# Will performance improve/decrease if I directly refer LESS in html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, less

I'm using LESS CSS and [Dot Less](https://github.com/dotless/dotless) in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I'm directly referring LESS using bundles

```
bundles.Add(new LessBundle("~/styles/templates").Include("~/Content/Stylesheets/Templates.less"));
```

But this [link](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-environments) saying if we use less.js in the html it will degrade the user performance. But i'm not using less.js in my project.

I've the following questions.

1. Shall I refer the less bundle directly in page?
2. If I refer LESS bundle directly, will it increase the performance?

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with ASP stuff, but logically: 1. Does it work? If so why not... 2. Everything you do with those bundles and whatever ASP specific stuff is performed at the ASP side (i.e. by the server or your dev. enviroment) so nothing in this regard can affect *user* performance (since user gets all his pages and stylesheets already rendered/preprocessed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not compare client side in browser version of less.js with Dot Less and bundle. The in browser version of less.js compiles your Less code client side (and does that again for each page request) and should not be used for production.
DOT Less compiles your Less code server side and bundle ensures that only the compiled CSS code loads in browser. Less code will only be compiled once and the compiled CSS will be used for each page request. You definitely should read: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Use in your pages `@Styles.render("~/styles/templates")` this should not influence your performance.

NB consider using http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%3a%20LESS cause it uses a newer version of Less.